# Function miscalculation

Tags: javascript

I have this function which is simply a sum and a product.
For some values ​​work for others not in the sense does not return the correct result.

```
Codia function (r, c) {
         return ((r + c) * (r + c + 1)); 
}
alert(Codia(1908229752,0));
```

Result obtained by the function: `3641340788326211000`

Result calculated by me: `3641340788326211256`

Can you tell me where am I wrong.

Comment: shouldn't that be `function Codia () {}`?

Comment: @Teemu - Numbers in JS can hold a very large value. `3641340788326211000` isn't even anywhere near it. However, it is definitely greater than the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` value in most browsers.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 You're right, I was mixing the largest possible integer and number ...

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript isn't designed to calculate with great accuracy. Once you have floats and doubles or numbers that are greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (which is 9007199254740991), numbers will start to lose their accuracy. Here's a comparison of your expected answer and the max safe integer:

```
3,641,340,788,326,211,256    EXPECTED ANSWER
    9,007,199,254,740,991    MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
```

To fix this, either use a library that is designed to do arithmetics with big numbers, or design a new algorithm yourself.

Here's an example using [BigNumber.js](http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/) which returns the correct answer of 3641340788326211256: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/jj47touj/

Comment: It may be more meaningful if you compare the number, complete with thousand separators, aligned with the number that OP posted so it's clear which one is bigger.

Comment: Thank you, it works.
1) But if the formula looked like this: ((r + c) * (r + c + 1)) / 2 + r
How should I change the formula?
2) What is the maximum value calculated?
3) In the second issue new BigNumber (0)). C.join ("") because .c.join ("")? 4

Comment: 4)If I have this function function Dec (str) {
var s = Math.floor ((Math.sqrt (1 + 8 * str) - 1) / 2);
this.par str = - s * (s + 1) / 2;
this.cod = s - this.par;
}
How can I change it using the library BigNumber.js

Thank you.

Comment: @angel - There are corresponding methods for every arithmetic operators. So `+` would be `.plus()`, `/` would be `.div()`, etc. There is no maximum value according to BigNumber's documentation; apparently the number can go as big as you want. I did `.c.join("")` just to log the readable value into the console. You can also do `.toString()` to get the string containing the number.

Comment: Additionally, there is a complete list of methods you can use [right here](http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#prototype-methods) if you need help converting your formula.

Comment: @Derek 朕會功夫 If you do not mind you could convert these two methods, I get confused a bit. xD
Cod function (r, c) {return ((r + c) * (r + c + 1)) / 2 + r; }
Dec function (str) {
var s = Math.floor ((Math.sqrt (1 + 8 * str) - 1) / 2);
this.par str = - s * (s + 1) / 2;
this.cod = s - this.par;
}

Comment: @angel - `this.par str =` isn't valid JavaScript... And why are there `this`'s?

Comment: Sorry function Dec(str){
 var s = Math.floor((Math.sqrt (1 + 8 * str) - 1) / 2);
 this.par = str - s * (s + 1) / 2;
 this.cod = s - this.par;
} could you give me a hand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61826/discussion-between-derek--and-angel).

Comment: Error: new BigNumber() base out of range: 0 what?